# Resume from puppeteer after script terminates/reboot

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm monitoring a financial website which requires OTP and whatnot.

1. My issue is, if the puppeteer script breaks, human intervention is required to get through the OTP/2FA again.
2. Refreshing the page (`F5`) also causes the site to request for OTP/2FA again. Meaning, page content has to be restored as well, I can't just load a URL with cookies set.

Is there a way to restore/maintain that session in headless chrome when my script breaks/terminates or machine reboots and be able to resume from it?

After some googling, I found this, [Puppeteer: how to store a session (including cookies, page state, local storage, etc) and continue later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987585/puppeteer-how-to-store-a-session-including-cookies-page-state-local-storage) but its terms are unfamiliar to me and I'm not certain if it is what I'm looking for.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Your item 2 means that the data you'd need is likely stored in a way you don't have access to. For example, in an isolated variable. There's no way to save the full state of a page. The accepted answer in the question you linked says as much. You're mostly limited to saving/restoring cookies.

Comment: Ok, i don't think there is anything that special. How it probably works is that, if the main page/frame is loaded, it will clear all cookies, thus, leading to the OTA/2FA page again. Perhaps succinctly, I'm asking, is there a way to inject page contents and navigate from there?

Comment: Yes, you can inject custom content. However, that content won't be hooked up to the page's javascript and you're unlikely to be able to hook it up yourself.

Comment: Maybe a better way to describe what I'm after is, can Chrome save its state like a virtual machine and resume at at a later time

Comment: Nope, that's a not a thing.